# Non-linear matrix equation solvable with linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, least-squares, kronecker-product

Consider the matrix equation $${\bf X}^k\bf {A = B}$$
Which we want to solve for $\bf X$

We can put A and B in a "block-vector": $v = [{\bf A}^T,{\bf 0},\cdots,{\bf 0},{\bf B}^T]^T$, assume there exists a matrix:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}\bf I&\bf 0&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf X_1&\bf 0&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf 0&\bf X_2&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf 0&\bf 0&\bf 0&\bf X_k&\bf 0\end{bmatrix}$$ With $k$ nr of $X$s in it.
$$\|{\bf C(Mv-d)}\|_F^2$$ with $\bf C$ (like a boundary condition) encoding that fit to first and last element is important and disregard what happens in between.

Finally solve wrt $\bf X$, for example by vectorization, Kronecker products and a new term regularizing to get the $\bf 0$s to $\bf 0$ and a set of equation systems tying the first $\bf X$ to the second, et.c. $+\|{\bf X_i-X_{i+1}}\|_F^2$. When solved, if successful the ${\bf X_i}$ should be so close to each other that we can take for example the mean value of them as the solution for ${\bf X}$.

---

Would this be a reasonable approach of linearizing the equation or am I missing something important?

---

**EDIT** I found a potential brain fart. If expressed as equations, I think we need the diagonal strip of $\bf -I$ below, but I am not sure yet.

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}\bf I&\bf 0&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf X_1&\bf -I&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf 0&\bf X_2&\bf -I&\cdots&\bf 0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf 0&\bf 0&\bf 0&\bf X_k&\bf -I\end{bmatrix}$$

---

**NEW EDIT** None of the above two seem to work very well. I do get some matrix as a solution so the $$+\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \|{\bf X_i - X_{i+1}}\|_2^2$$ seems to work as intended, but any of the $\bf X_l$ is several orders of magnitude too small to make any sense. Still I can't find any theoretical reason for why it should not work so my current assumption is that I have made a mistake in the implementation. Another possibility is that maybe it is in general quite hard to even find one solution to such polynomial matrix equations so that some kind of regularization that I have not thought about would be required.

---

**Newest edit!** I realized I need one more line in the matrices and one more $\bf 0$ block in the right hand side vector, like this:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}\bf I&\bf 0&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf X_1&\bf -I&\bf 0&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf 0&\bf X_2&\bf -I&\cdots&\bf 0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\cdots&\bf 0\\\bf 0&\bf 0&\bf 0&\bf X_k&\bf -I\\\bf 0 &\cdots& \bf 0& \bf 0 & \bf I\end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{bmatrix}\bf A\\\bf 0\\\bf 0\\ \vdots\\\bf 0\\\bf B\end{bmatrix}$$

---

This way **both** $\bf A,B$ get their very own equations for fixation a.k.a. "boundary conditions". Without any similar fixation for $\bf B$ as we had for $\bf A$ before there is no guarantee what properties our $\bf X_k$ should be getting when solving for $M$.

Comment: In the first equation, there is an $X$. How is it related to the $X_{i}$'s? Also, what is $d$?

Comment: The $X_i$ are candidate blocks of matrices of the same size as $X$, $M$ is what we are solving for. $d=v$. If we solve for $M$ and build least squares terms on $M$ pushing the $X_i$ to be close to each others if we solve the equation then the $X_i$ should approximate $X$ in the original equation. If I am thinking right, by recursion the equation system will be $X_k \cdots X_1A = B$ which should be $X^kA=B$ if the $X_l$ are the same

Comment: Trying to fit $Mv$ to $d$ is like trying to fit $[A^{\top}, X_{1}A^{\top}, 0, \ldots, 0]^{\top}$ to $[A^{\top}, 0, \ldots, 0, B^{\top}]^{\top}$. Is that what you want?

Comment: not if I use $C$ to reduce the importance of fit of all the places of $0$s in $v$. ( weighted least squares ).

Comment: $C$ gives equal importance to both $v$ and $d$, it just factors out. Anything that minimizes $\|Mv-d\|_{F}^{2}$ will also minimize $\|C(Mv-d\|_{F}^{2})$. No?

Comment: Or do you mean the entries of $C$ serve to give different weights to entries of $v$?

Comment: If C is a diagonal matrix ( I hope ) we can make the Frobenius norm selectively not care about the fits in the spaces for 0s in the vectors by setting those diagonal elements in $C$ to 0.

Comment: Why not solve $Y A = B$ for $Y$ and then take the $k$-th root? The latter is trivial if $Y$ is diagonalizable. Is it not diagonalizable in your case, is that the problem?

Comment: The k'th root is not well defined for anythong more complicated than $\mathbb R$

Comment: Nevertheless, why don't you write $X^k = B A^{-1}$?

Comment: @Gribouillis We don't know if either of $\bf A, B$ are invertible.

Comment: But one has $\text{Ker}(A) \subset \text{Ker}(B)$, this could be a first direction to explore.

Comment: @Gribouillis : I am interested in general methods, not peculiar details. If the method works it will be solved automatically in the best way ( least squares sense ) if we minimize the Frobenius norm. I expect the rank of both $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ to be able to be anything from 1 in a million to full rank.