# Linearizations for matrix polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, reference-request, linearization

Having tried a bit on my own with limited success [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408572/non-linear-matrix-equation-solvable-with-linear-algebra), I'm wondering what other methods there exist to try and linearize this type of polynomial matrix equations:

$$P({\bf X}) = \sum_{k=0}^N {\bf C_kX}^k = {\bf 0}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "linearize" ? An operation like one finds with Kronecker products ?

Comment: @JeanMarie : Any way that turns it into a system solvable with linear least squares.

Comment: I am not sure that there is such a general  method.

Comment: @JeanMarie : Me neither. That is why I'm trying to build one. Polynomial matrix equations are literally everywhere.

Comment: Could you confirm that the $C_k$ are matrices ? A more general question (in order not to privilegize left multiplication) would be to solve $P({\bf X}) = \sum_{k=0}^N {\bf C_kX}^k {\bf D_k}= {\bf 0}.$

Comment: @JeanMarie : Yes they are matrices, I assume your extension would not be so difficult once we have managed to solved the first.

Comment: I think your issue is too restrictive, because in many real cases for example the "square" of a unknown matrix $X$ appears often under the form $XAX$ (even if it is not a square, stricly speaking).